# How can i get result from model in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Good day, i'm trying to get the result from my model that called with `Mainmodel` through my controller, my controller is `MainController`.

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Mainmodel;

class MainController extends Controller
{


    function index(){
        echo "Kok, direct akses sih?";
    }

    function get_menu(){
         $menu = app\Mainmodel::request_menu();
         dd($menu);
    }

}
```

Here is my model

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mainmodel extends Model
{
    function request_menu(){
        $menu = DB::table('menu')
                ->orderBy('[order]', 'desc')
                ->get();
         return $menu;
    }
}
```

my routes

```
Route::get('menu','MainController@get_menu');
```

with my script above i get this

> FatalErrorException in MainController.php line 17: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\app\Mainmodel' not found

how can i fix this ? thanks in advance.

Note: I'm bit confuse with laravel. I'm using codeigniter before. And i have a simple question. In laravel for request to database should i use model ? or can i just use my controller for my request to database.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Change `use app\Mainmodel;` to `use App\Mainmodel;`in your controller

Comment: when i use laravel only use `use Mainmodel;`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you're using Models in the best way. You should use a model for each table in your database. Have a look at: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it's because your using `app` rather than `App` for the namespace.

Try changing:

```
app\Mainmodel
```

To:

```
App\Mainmodel
```

Alternatively, you can add a `use` statement to the top of the class and then just reference the class i.e.:

```
use App\Mainmodel;
```

Then you can just do something like:

```
Mainmodel::request_menu();
```

---

The way you're currently using you models is not the way `Eloquent` should be used. As I mentioned in my comment you should create a model for each table in your database (or at least for the majority of use cases).

To do this run:

```
php artisan make:model Menu
```

Then in the newly created `Menu` model add:

```
protected $table = 'menu';
```

This is because Laravel's default naming convention is singular for the class name and plural for the table name. Since your table name is **menu** and not **menus** you just need to tell Laravel to use a different table name.

Then your controller would look something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Menu;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Kok, direct akses sih?";
    }

    public function get_menu()
    {
        $menu = Menu::orderBy('order', 'desc')->get();
        dd($menu);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @YVS1102 Try running `composer dumpautoload` from the command line

Comment: Ok, now the error is change. Non-static method App\Mainmodel::request_menu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: @YVS1102 that's because you are calling a non-static method, make the function static `static function request_menu`

Comment: @YVS1102 I've update my answer to show you how you can set up a Model for your menu table.

Comment: It fix my problem. So, i just need to keep model empty then i create the condition in controller ?

Comment: @YVS1102 You can leave it empty but you'll  end up adding to it. Typically, you would add relationships and scopes to your model and potentially more. Have a look at the video I added in my above comment as well as https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by different solution. The solution is you don't have to call `request_menu();` you can get it in your controller.

**MainController**

```
use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function get_menu(){
             $menu =  DB::table('menu')
            ->orderBy('Your_Field_Name', 'DESC')
            ->get();

             dd($menu);
}
```